# Kivy Scroll View - another "does not scroll" question

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I've been looking through questions all day but cant get this to work. I know its probably a simple solution but just cant find it so I'm sorry to ask, Why is my scrollview not working!!

The code uses a loop to generate labels in a BoxLayout and adds this BoxLayout to the ScrollView, the loop works, but when the ScrollView is open it won't scroll to the top. I think I have defined heights appropriately so the final BoxLayout knows its self.height but when I use height: self.height in the kv file the scrolview gets pushed off the top of the screen and I can only see the last item by dragging it down a bit, it won't scroll any further then one item and then bounces back off the screen. If I explicitly define height with a value "height: 1800" lets say, then the scroll works better. But the problem is that I need the scroll to work for any number of iterations of the original loop, so sometimes more labels/boxlayouts and sometimes less so defining an explicit hight value wont really work.

I have set size_hint_y: none and height: self.height but this generates the problem described above.

Thanks for the help!!!

Here is the code snipit.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '640')

class BoxWithOutline(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Box(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Temp_Box = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", padding = "20px", spacing = "20px" )
        for _ in range(25):
            B1 = BoxWithOutline()
            B1.add_widget(Button(text = str(_)))

            B2 = BoxLayout(orientation = "horizontal" )          
            B2.add_widget(Label(text = "Correct"))
            B2.add_widget(Label(text = "Incorrect"))

            B1.add_widget(B2)

            Temp_Box.add_widget(B1)

        self.add_widget(Temp_Box)

class Scroll(ScrollView):
    pass


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Scroll()

Test().run()
```

And the .KV file

```
<Box>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "20px"
    spacing: "20px"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.height


<BoxWithOutline>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "50px"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Line:
            rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

<Scroll>:
    Box:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try
height : self.minimum_height
in your Box class, that works always for me.
Are you using Temp_Box just for the extra spacing and padding? You could remove it and use self.add_widget instead of Temp_Box.add_widget.

Comment: ah yes, well kinda. I used height : self.minimum_height but this didn't work but as you said, why the Temp_Box. Your right, there was no reason for this so I just used self.add_widget in the loop and this worked. I guess things were maube overlapping and the incorrect self.height was being used, or at least the value that self.height had was not what I intended! Taking out the Temp_Box made everything work!!